# Switch to another ContainerView from inside a ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I made an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

One ViewController contains two ContainerViews. The user can switch between them with SegmentedControl.

But, how can I switch to the other ContainerView without the SegmentedControl, e.g. with a button?

Actually I have this code:

```
        let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login")
        self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

This opens the other ContainerView, but as single VC, not inside the parent ViewController.

What can I do to reach the other ContainerView shown in the parent VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to set the `IBoutlets` from `ContainerViews` `viewControllers` too to call them separately using `uibuttons` action.

> assign same class to both parentViewcontroller and containerView using identity inspector see image.

[image]

> connect IBOutlet as well like parentViewController see image

[image]

Now can access from class using `uibutton` action.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean I should have IBOutlets from ParentViewController in ContainerView file?

Comment: i think the file of all `ContainerViews` are same as its `parentViewController` from where you implementing `SegmentedControl` ..

Comment: No, I have separate [Filename].swift for every ViewController/ContainerViewController. Is that wrong?

Comment: yes every `viewController` can have its separate file name obvious ..but you can assign same class to `containerView`s `viewController` in order to access it from button over it ..

Comment: You mean ParentViewController and ChildContainerViewController should have the same class in Storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121529/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-david).

Comment: Okay, I'm in the Chat.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your parent view controllers's child's like

```
parentViewController.childViewControllers.indexOf(self)
```

you got the index, means you can get the Controller then you can show it

Comment: Don't really understand how to handle it now. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: let aParentVC = UIViewController.init()
let aChildA = UIViewController.init()
let aChildB = UIViewController.init()
let aChildC = UIViewController.init()

aParentVC.addChildViewController(aChildA)
aParentVC.addChildViewController(aChildB)
aParentVC.addChildViewController(aChildC)
This is what you will do in your parent view controller to add the childs, this might be done through UI also. Now suppose one of your child has some event say a button tap. On this tap you wish to swich your child

Comment: then you can just call you parent and iterate through your parent view controller's childs like above and this is how you will get the refrence of your child. Now pass the child to your show method